# Filter by date in Qlik Cloud

Tags: business-intelligence, qliksense

I have sheet in Qlik Cloud, where I have dataset from whole month. I would like to filter this dataset by date or time - 1 day, 1 week, 12 hours... column with date/time in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss is in dataset for each row. Is possible insert some calendar? Or have you any idea?
Thanks for your answers ;)

Comment: Hi Alf, I'm not sure what your question means? Do you want to see a calendar object on screen?

Comment: Yes, whether is it possible. Some calendar with time is ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your data is loaded correctly, drag the field directly onto the sheet. This will create a look-up box that can be searched.

You can see if the field has been identified correctly as a date as it will appear like this on the field selector

[image: date example]

**Another Option**

Create a filter box option and add your date field to it, the benefit of this is that you can have multiple filters in one place. Allowing users to pick the part of the date relevant to them. For example showing the year field, the month field and the date field in one

**one more option**

Using non-standard Qlik extensions you can achieve the functionality that you require. [SenseDateRangePicker](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/5697a878dcc497f80ed514bf) is an extension that provides extended date selection functionality.

Comment: SenseDateRangePicker is good solution for my problem. I recommend this extension ;)